# jquery ajax same data for all http codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following ajax, and it works fine when I get a `200`, but when I get a `400` I get all sorts of extra data, is there a way to get the same data as the success for errors?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: getHost() + "/leaderboard/score?gameId=" + $("#gameId").val() + "&scoreId=" + $("#scoreId").val(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        showOutput(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        showOutput(data);
    }
});

function showOutput(data){
    $("pre code").text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    $('pre code').each(function(i, block){
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you face is that those callbacks take different parameters, for example to use complete it would be

```
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus ){
    showOutput(JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText));
}
```

the responseText is parsed since `showOutput` expects an object and not a JSON string.

Comment: Ahh, that is what I want

Answer (score 1):

You need `jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });`

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: getHost() + "/leaderboard/score?gameId=" + $("#gameId").val() + "&scoreId=" + $("#scoreId").val(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        // showOutput(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        // showOutput(data);
    }
}).always(function(data) {
    showOutput(data);
});

function showOutput(data){
    $("pre code").text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    $('pre code').each(function(i, block){
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
}
```

Note that `data` may not always be available (on error, you will get back a jqXHR), so you'll need to sanitize the code otherwise the `JSON.stringify` could throw an exception.